# Button not displaying in LinearLayout

Tags: android, button, android-layout

I am trying to add a `Button` in a `LinearLayout` after a `TextView` but it is not showing up.

Here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dip">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/tvChild"
        android:text="Children"
        android:textColor="#ffCCCC22" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The `TextView` is displayed correctly with proper text but instead of a `Button` I am getting a big blank space of three to four lines length.

What am I missing?

Comment: Change android:layout_width="fill_parent" of TextView to android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Or

In your LinearLayout tag add android:orientation="vertical"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dip"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dip" android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="5dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="17dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/tvChild"
            android:text="Children" android:textColor="#ffCCCC22"
            />
            <Button android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` instead of 
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for `TextView` and `Button`

Comment: Even if OP is new you should *not* ask for an upvote *and* answer acceptance.

Comment: Read what I wrote: Even if he is new you shouldn't do it. You can tell him *how to accept an answer*. Don't force the user to accept *your* answer or even upvote it. Your answer does not *explain* why your solution works. [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers)

Comment: I tell this only new user bcz every user dont know exact meaning of Accept answer..

Answer (score 6):

The problem was you were setting `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for the `TextView`, so it took full screen width just for displaying the `TextView`. And it was not able to display  the `Button`.

Here are two options for you :

1. Adding `TextView` and `Button` on a single row.

   Change the `layout_width` attribute of the `TextView` to `wrap_content`.
2. Adding `TextView` and `Button` vertically.

   Change `LinearLayout`'s orientation attribute to `vertical`.

Comment: Exactly.. I got it.. Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```