# Buttons no longer showing after fixing R cannot be resolved to a variable error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I ran into the dreaded "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error after doing a Project > Clean. I tracked the problem down to my main.XML file (wasnt the typical import.R in the java)  . It was giving an error along the lines of "error parsing XML" at the end of my LinearLayout. To fix it I had to clear out all the code in my main.XML, save the changes, then retype it. That fixed the R cannot be resolved. However, my buttons are no longer visible in either the graphical layout image or while running on a device. I have an edittext at the top which is still visible, but the buttons below it no longer show up. Project > Clean doesn't fix it, exiting and restarting Eclipse hasnt fixed it, typing in a harmless string or adding another button and saving hasnt fixed it. My gen file is there, and its showing the layout. Thoughts on where else to look?

Comment: Related: [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error) - [“R cannot be resolved to a variable”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable) - [Google Search: site:stackoverflow.com r cannot be resolved to a variable](https://www.google.dk/search?&q=site:stackoverflow.com+r+cannot+be+resolved+to+a+variable) - [StackOverflow Search: r cannot be resolved to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=r+cannot+be+resolved+to+a+variable)

Comment: Sorry, I was a little too quick there. I'm not sure your issue has much to do with the fact that it occurred after having the "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error. These might help though:
[Button not displaying in LinearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939215/button-not-displaying-in-linearlayout) - [Google Search: site:stackoverflow.com button not showing android](https://www.google.dk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+button+not+showing+android&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+button+not+showing+android). If not, try posting your XML.

Comment: Second set of links did the trick, much appreciated. Was just coincidence it happened after the R problem, was barking up the wrong tree ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aske B. answered the question for me with the links he provided, there was a problem in the the XML.